# CSS for spreading middle element, keeping the others fixed and pushed together in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/Lvgra13k/) shows, I have almost perfect behavior for *cutty* in the middle. It shows all text up to the point where the space allowed by the container (minus the fixed allotment for *fixy-x*'s) runs out, upon which, the text is cut off and ellipted.

```
.fixy-lefty { flex: 0; }
.fixy-righty { flex: 0; }
.cutty {
  display: inline;
  flex: 1;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The only change that I'd like to see now is that *fixy-righty* is not stuck to the right edge of the container (letting *cutty* steal all the space). I want the former to be right next to the latter **and** the latter to shrink according to the text in it. (Imagine that the right component is an icon that follows the main text. Then, in case the text in the middle component gets too wide, I want it to be ellipted.

So, I'm looking form something like this:

> |X| _ |short-text| _ |Y| _______
>     |X| _ |very-looooong-te...| _ |Y|

I've tried adding a fourth component to the right of the *cutty-righty*. I tried encapsulating middle and right one with a div. I tried different settings for *flex* (altering shrinkage but not expansion) as well as different displays. Setting the container to *justify-content: flex-start;* and/or the right one to *flex: 1 0 1;* leads nowhere to be specific.

The result is nothing, zero, nada, ziltch. Is it possible to achieve CSSing at all or do I have to rely on JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove `flex: 1;` from `.cutty` as it is not needed. Right now, you're asking it to fill all available space with this container (`flex-grow: 1`). By removing this flex value it  will behave the way you want it to, if there's enough content `.cutty` will expend and take all available space.

```js
$("input").click(function() {
  var target = $("span.target")[0];
  target.textContent = "Very long text that should be cut and ellipted";
});
```

```css
div,
span {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.outer {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row {
  border-color: blue;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  border-color: blueviolet;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.right {
  flex: 3;
  border-color: green;
}

.fixy-lefty {
  flex: 0;
  border-color: burlywood;
}

.fixy-righty {
  flex: 0;
  border-color: orange;
}

.cutty {
  display: inline;
  /* flex: 1; (not needed) */
  border-color: pink;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.def {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  border-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <span class="fixy-lefty">Uno</span>
      <span class="cutty target">Duo</span>
      <span class="fixy-righty">Tro</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <span class="def">12</span>
      <span class="def">34</span>
      <span class="def">56</span>
      <span class="def">78</span>
      <span class="def">90</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <span class="fixy-lefty">Uno</span>
      <span class="cutty">Very long text that needs to</span>
      <span class="fixy-righty">Tro</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <span class="def">12</span>
      <span class="def">34</span>
      <span class="def">56</span>
      <span class="def">78</span>
      <span class="def">90</span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<input type="button" value="Click me">
```

Available on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqjhxnrm/) as well